# Can NPC's be revived also?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

I was in the graveyard in Cyseal and one of the NPC's died.

> I dug up the grave containing Dave. The tutorial popup suggested me to flee battle. I attempted it to kill Dave but when I saw he was way too strong for me I fleed. Resulting in Dave killing my 3rd party member Madoka and Murphy, the dog I was doing a quest for.

I did not save that game. My main characters came out fine. I had one resurrection scroll.

Could I have used that scroll to resurrect the NPC?
What are the effects of reviving NPC's? Is it different if they die by me killing them and by other causes?
If they are dead, will they just indefinitely lie there?

Answer (score 4):

When NPCs die, they stay dead.  You can't use a scroll of resurrection to bring them back - that only works on your own party members.

Bodies seem to stick around, at least in my experience.  I've gone back to areas I cleared hours upon hours ago, and the remains from my previous battles are still present.